# Open Data Kit 2.0: Any expression in the "condition" column of survey sheet throws an error

Tags: javascript, odk

I am currently designing a household survey using Application Designer 2.1.0. When I include an expression that has to be evaluated in condition or constraint columns or in the calculates sheet (calculation column), an error is generated when I try to fill in an answer for the corresponding question using the preview functionality of Application Designer. [A screenshot of the error is shown in image 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7P5F.png)
This is an attempt where I had tried to make it work by transferring any expressions to the calculates sheet.

But the common error generated in all of my attempts is that the variable, mobileNumber in this case, is not defined. XLSX Converter does not generate an error.

I have, in fact, defined the variable using the name column in the survey section sheet. [A screenshot of this is shown in image 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxNJ2.png) The cell where variable/table header column name is defined is highlighted in yellow.

When I try to include the variable name in single quotes ('mobileNumber') as directed by ODK documentation, an error is generated by XLSX Converter [as shown in image 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi1V2.png)

I find the same errors show up even if I try to use the constraint column with the expression.

I'm sure I'm getting something basic wrong. The survey has to be field tested in 2 weeks! 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is due to LibreOffice/OpenOffice auto-correcting single quotes into smart quotes. See https://forum.opendatakit.org/t/expression-in-condition-column-not-successfully-evaluated/15736/5 for more details.